# Julia - Why using macro @info generates bad @code_warntype performance?

Tags: string, performance, julia, display

I was wondering why using @info generates bad `err` variable performance: `Any`. See the next MWE:

```
function bad_performance()
    @info "demo"
end



julia> @code_warntype bad_performance()
Variables
  #self#::Core.Compiler.Const(test, false)
  level::Base.CoreLogging.LogLevel
  std_level::Base.CoreLogging.LogLevel
  group::Symbol
  _module::Module
  logger::Union{Nothing, Base.CoreLogging.AbstractLogger}
  id::Symbol
  file::String
  line::Int64
  msg::String
  err::Any
```

What should I change to avoid it or should I ignore this Red warning from @code_warntype?

Note: it also generates yellow warning for logger variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because you can create your own loggers and set them as the current logger, which uses global, non-const variables. You can see the same phenomenon more simply with

```
julia> printstdout(str) = print(stdout, str)
printstdout (generic function with 1 method)

julia> @code_warntype optimize=true printstdout("hello")
Variables
  #self#::Core.Const(printstdout)
  str::String

Body::Union{Nothing, Int64}
1 ─ %1  = Main.print::Core.Const(print)
│   %2  = Main.stdout::Any
│   %3  = (isa)(%2, Cthulhu.TextWidthLimiter)::Bool
└──       goto #3 if not %3
2 ─ %5  = π (%2, Cthulhu.TextWidthLimiter)
│   %6  = invoke %1(%5::Cthulhu.TextWidthLimiter, _2::String)::Union{Nothing, Int64}
└──       goto #4
3 ─ %8  = Main.print(Main.stdout, str)::Union{Nothing, Int64}
└──       goto #4
4 ┄ %10 = φ (#2 => %6, #3 => %8)::Union{Nothing, Int64}
└──       return %10
```

Even though

```
julia> typeof(stdout)
Base.TTY
```

it's inferred as `Any` because

```
julia> isconst(Base, :stdout)
false
```

It has to be that way to allow `redirect_stdout`.

The good thing is that the poor logger inference only matters if you're actually logging; if it's wrapped in an `if` block that doesn't get triggered, the impact on performance is usually minimal. If you find that it matters for your case, put the `@info` into a separate function which you can call from the function that needs to be fast.

Comment: Thank you for your answer :) Is it the correct procedure? Ask here when I don't know what to do with a @code_warntype specific bad performance? What you have said is not written in the doc isn't it?

Comment: I'd recommend always starting from `@profile` data, and focusing on the forms of instability that are causing performance problems. When viewed with ProfileView.jl, you'll see red bars that come from inference problems; the wider they are, the more consequential they are (if they are in the top row).